# Do edit pages and view pages need to have the same basic layout?

Tags: forms, user-interface

From a design and usability perspective is it best that an edit page mimics the layout of the view page?

Our view page is very dense. The data is tightly packed together, but when editing there are going to be extra controls next to each entry field. If we leave the layout the same it will be overly crowded. Will this cause problems with usability if the fields are rearranged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It definitely impairs usability. Two hazards of re-arranging fields are:

- Confusing users about which field they are editing
- Making it difficult for users to find the field they want to edit.

These problems are exacerbated on high-density pages.

There are some times when this is ok. The best example I can think of is where the editor and viewer are different users. Another (more ambiguous) case is a situation where the edit screen needs to be highly optimized for fast throughput.

If possible, you might consider splitting the screen up, or making collapsable regions to give the user (and the screen) a little room to breathe.

Answer (score 2):

In general you want to keep the edit page as simillar as possible to the view page. In general. There are cases where this just doesn't make sense especially if you have to input a lot of extra data that is not shown in the view, which it sounds like is your case.

What I would try and do is make sure you continue to group and order the fields in the same manner as if you were viewing so while they might be in slightly different places at least they would be logically grouped the same.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon your workflow.

If the user has to go back and forth between edit and view, it will be very confusing to the person, as fields may jump around, they might lose which field they are on, etc.

If your view page is very dense, you might try breaking it up into sections, each with its own edit function. You could have it shoot to its own edit page or be all 'web 2.0' and throw up a lightbox with the section edit form over the view page.

Answer (score 1):

The more that things are similar, typically, the easier it is for a user to use.  I don't know what your particular layout looks like but from a general point of view, a crowded view is often hard to look at and cluttering it up with additional controls would make it worse.

As much as I'm not a spreadsheet guy, editing in Excel or similar products is easy because it doesn't clog up the view with lots of controls.  The edit panel is the view panel.  For my own products, when things are consistent, the users are generally less confused.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem.  What I did was have a View page that lets you see everything, but you need to drill into individual edit pages for logical sections.  Within the logical sections the fields are always in the same order (and with the same labels) as on the view page.  It's things like this which make your application just feel a bit nicer.

Don't throw everything onto a massive edit page just because they all relate to the same thing in your database model.  Break them out into sets that make sense each with 3-7 fields on them.

If they really need to edit everything (like when creating a new thing) then I would go for a wizard approach which steps through through, presents a view-only summary and then lets them save.